# Ejecutar CMD pidiendo derechos de Administrador

Tags: java, windows, javafx, permisos

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto javafx. En un momento del programa necesito pedir al usuario derechos Elevados para realizar una determinada acción.

¿Cómo puedo codificar esta acción?

Mi programa no necesita ningún permiso para funcionar de manera correcta, únicamente para esta acción se necesita.
Para ser más específico sobre mi problema voy a dar una breve descripción de mi código y lo que hace:

Mi programa detecta unos aparatos que yo he diseñado. El problema que tengo es que en ocasiones necesito cambiar la VLAN ID de mi tarjeta de red. Para ello lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
public void VlanChanged (int vlanId) { 
     StopDeviceSearch();
        
     try {
          Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
          String cmd = "cmd /c \"Echo S|powershell set-netadapter -InterfaceDescription 'Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller' -VlanID " + vlanId + "\"";
        
          rt.exec(cmd);
     } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println (e);
     }
            
     RestarDeviceSearch();
}
```

Si ejecuto myProyect.jar como administrador el código anterior funciona de manera correcta, pero si no lo ejecuto como administrador el código anterior no funciona.

Mi preguntas es:
¿Podría ejecutar mi programa y cuando el usuario active la función "VlanChanged" que mi programa solicite al usuario permisos de administrador para ejecutar CMD como administrador y poder realizar la acción de cambio de VLAN ID de manera correcta?

He probado con el comando "runas /profile /user: Administrator" pero no funciona. Lo que a mi me gustaría que pasara es que se abriese el cartel de Windows que te pregunta:
"¿Quieres permitir que esta aplicación haga cambios en el dispositivo?"
Que la ventana tiene el título: "Control de cuentas de usuario"

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos,

Comment: creo que lo simple es usar un instalador que deje el programa instalado como administrador, asi cada ves que se llame a la aplicación esta correrá como admin, puedes hacer el instalador con winrar y selecionar, solicitar permisos de administracion al crear el instalador

Comment: La cuestión es que el programa puede ser utilizado por usuarios que no tenga permisos de administrador, si hago lo que porpones dicho usuarios no podrán utilizar la aplicación. Mi intención es que la aplicación funcione sin permisos (exceptuando cuando se quiera hacer uso de la funcionalidad de cambio de VLAN, en ese instante es cuando quiero que se le solicite al usuario los derechos de administrador); De esta manera los usuarios sin permiso de administrador podrán usar la aplicación sin problemas, pero no podrán usar la funcionalidad de cambio de VLAN.

Comment: pero eso es super facil, sacas esa funcionalidad de tu aplicadcion, y la instalas como una nueva que necesita permisos administrador, cuando llames para ejecutar esa otra aplicacion desde la actual saltará la solucitud de permisos.

Comment: las aplicaciones o tienen permisos o no tienen permisos, cuando tu otorgas permiso automaticamnete toda la aplicacion tiene derechos de admin, por eso hacerlo en una aplicacion aparte para que solo esa aplicacion tenga derechos de admin

Comment: vale, eso lo he conseguido creando un ".bat" que ejecuta el cambio de VLAN ID. Luego creo un acceso directo del archivo ".bat" y en propiedades del acceso directo defino que siempre se ejecute como administrador.

Comment: @John ya sé que las aplicaciones o no tienen peermisos de administrador o los tiene toda la aplicación. Lo que no quiero es que siempre deba ejecutarse con esos derechos. Lo que me gustaría es que la aplicación se ejecutara sin esos derechos de  administrador y solo en el caso de que el usuario necesitara hacer uso de la funcionalidad de cambio de VLAN ID se solicitaran dichos derechos para toda la aplicación. No se si me estoy explicando correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nativamente no es posibles pasar de una consola sin privilegios a una con privilegios en Windows, pero hay una opción y es instalar el comando `gsudo` este comando busca imitar al comando `sudo` en Linux permite ejecutar comandos con permisos de administrados o elevar la consola a una con privilegios, al ejecutar el comando solicita que ingreses las credenciales de admirador o aceptes la elevación de permisos.

El proyecto es el siguiente: `https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo` si el proyecto te es útil recuerda agradecer con una estrella.

Ahí encontraras los métodos de instalación puedes bajar el ejecutable y dejarlo en una ruta o como en mi caso instalar el comando con `Chocolatey`.

Como instale el comando con `Chocolatey` la ruta del comando es `C:\\tools\\gsudo\\Current\\gsudo`.

Ejemplo:

```
public class ElevacionPermisos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Comando que necesita permisos de administrador para ser ejecutado.
            String command = "cmd /c C:\\tools\\gsudo\\Current\\gsudo net session";

            // Ejecutamos y obtenemos el proceso
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            // En caso el proceso tarde, esperamos a que finalice
            proc.waitFor();

            // Lógica para imprimir el mensaje de salida
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // Logica para imprimir el mensaje de error si falla el comando
            isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream());
            rdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
                System.err.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Mensaje que retorna el comando después de aceptar la elevación de permisos: `No hay entradas en la lista.`

Mensaje que retorna el comando si cancelo la elevación de permisos: `Error: The operation was canceled by the user`

Comment: Voy a probar esta solución, tiene muy buena pinta. Cuando lo tenga te indico si me ha funcionado.

Comment: @Eduardo_Altair según los requerimientos de funcionamiento creo que cumple con todo lo que describes, espero que puedas solventar el problema.

Comment: He probado esta solución y me ha funcionado a la perfección, procedo a marcar la respuesta como correcta. MUCHAS GRACIAS